# numpy array with diagonal equal to zero and [x,y] =-[y,x]

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to create a `N x N` array in `numpy` such that the diagonal is zero and `[x,y] = -[y,x]`.

For example:

```
np.array([[[0,12, 2],
[-12, 0, 3],
[-2, -3, 0]],])
```

The values inside the array can be any float.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be with [`scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

def diag_inverted(n):
    l = n*(n-1)//2
    out = squareform(np.random.randn(l))
    out[np.tri(len(out),k=-1,dtype=bool)] *= -1
    return out
```

Another with `array-assignment` and `masking` -

```
def diag_inverted_v2(n):
    l = n*(n-1)//2
    m = np.tri(n, k=-1, dtype=bool)    
    out = np.zeros((n,n),dtype=float)
    out[m] = np.random.randn(l)
    out[m.T] = -out.T[m.T]
    return out
```

Sample runs -

```
In [148]: diag_inverted(2)
Out[148]: 
array([[ 0.        , -0.97873798],
       [ 0.97873798,  0.        ]])

In [149]: diag_inverted(3)
Out[149]: 
array([[ 0.        , -2.2408932 , -1.86755799],
       [ 2.2408932 ,  0.        ,  0.97727788],
       [ 1.86755799, -0.97727788,  0.        ]])

In [150]: diag_inverted(4)
Out[150]: 
array([[ 0.        , -0.95008842,  0.15135721, -0.4105985 ],
       [ 0.95008842,  0.        ,  0.10321885, -0.14404357],
       [-0.15135721, -0.10321885,  0.        , -1.45427351],
       [ 0.4105985 ,  0.14404357,  1.45427351,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: I want [x,y] = -[y,x]

Comment: so the above solutions are wonderful. I'm just wondering what is the difference between those solutions and that posted by @QuangHoang?

Comment: @codingknob Just different ways to get to the desired output I think.@QuangHoang's one has more arithmetic operations, so that could be one big difference.

Comment: @codingknob Actually, the solutions here are better  because they do not subtract two different random numbers at each postition. For normal distribution the latter happens to work (though it changes the variance) but if you want something else like a uniform distribution, then good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
size = 3

a = np.random.normal(0,1, (size, size))

ret = (a-a.transpose())/2
```

Output (random):

```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.11872306,  0.46792054],
       [-0.11872306,  0.        ,  0.12530741],
       [-0.46792054, -0.12530741,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Why are you dividing by two?

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I see no reason as why :-). Thanks